# convert huge big xml to xlsx

Tags: xml, xls

there's a way to convert for example 200mb of xml file in a csv/xls?

I try from excel but crash, also if pc have 64mb of ram. I also try free converter, but are limited also on payment.

Someone have some advise for that?

Regards from Enrico.

Comment: You can use XSLT for that

Comment: Hi @Yitzhak Khabinsky how? :)

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Please provide whatever you can ##1-4 on my previous comment. Otherwise, your question is not actionable.